# Install ArangoDB3 ubuntu lxd (Qnap NAS) FATAL Error 132

Tags: ubuntu, fatal-error, arangodb, apt, lxd

[Following the instructions](https://arangodb.com/download-major/ubuntu/) to install ArangoDB 3.11.4-1 at Ubuntu 22 the package manager is running into a FATAL Error.

**Important**: Ubuntu 22.04 installed as **LXD-Container** (ContainerStation 3 / QTS 5.0 QNAP TS-451+ 16 GB RAM Intel [Celeron J1900](https://www.techsavvy.de/prozessoren/intel_celeron_j1900/) 4 Core 2 GHz)

```
Setting up arangodb3 (3.11.4-1) ...
Illegal instruction
FATAL ERROR: EXIT_CODE_RESOLVING_FAILED for code 132 - could not resolve exit code 132
dpkg: error processing package arangodb3 (--configure):
 installed arangodb3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 132
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arangodb3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas how to solve this or what is the reason for this? My only idea is, the CPU doesn't match the requirements of Advanced Vector Extensions (**AVX**). If so, I want to try the [emulator](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/software-development-emulator.html) to fix it. My goal is simple to install ArangoDB and get familiar with AQL.

Comment: Yes, ArangoDB 3.11 requires AVX which is not supported by your CPU. You could try an older version. AFAIK 3.10 has more relaxed requirements.